# a vector space isomorphism : solution space with a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a sepcific property

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

We consider $B\dot{x}=Ax, x(0)=x^0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, an Initial Value Problem with $A,B$ real $n\times n$ matrices.

A global solution of this IVP  is a differentiable function $x(t):\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$  such that $\delta(x(t))=0$ where $\delta= (A-B{d\over dt})$

Now $V=\{x(t): x(t) \text{ is a global solu}\}$ is a vector space over reals and

$W=\{ x^0\in \mathbb{R}^n: x^0 \text{ is a initial value of the above IVP for which the IVP has a global solu} \}$

could anyone tell me how $W$ is a vector space and $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic?
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that $W$ is a vector space: Assume that $x_1^0$ and $x_2^0$ are different initial values where there is a global solution. Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the corresponding solutions. Then, since $V$ is a vector space, for all $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, the mapping $\lambda x_1+\mu x_2$ is a global solution. Moreover it satisfies
$$
(\lambda x_1+\mu x_2)(0) = \lambda x_1^0 + \mu x_2^0,
$$
which means that there is a global solution for the initial value $\lambda x_1^0+\mu x_2^0$, i.e. $\lambda x_1^0+\mu x_2^0 \in W$.

Hint for the second part: look at the mapping
$$
V \to W, x\mapsto x(0)
$$
and use a suitable uniqueness result for the initial value problem.